# Sunspot Solr: How to boost by popularity field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

I've added a "popularity" field to Solr as an external field.

"./solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/schema.xml"

```
<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">

  <!-- ... -->

  <types>
    <fieldType name="ext_popularity_field" keyField="id" defVal="1.0" class="solr.ExternalFileField"/>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="popularity" type="ext_popularity_field" />
  </fields>

  <!-- ... -->

  <listener event="newSearcher"   class="org.apache.solr.schema.ExternalFileFieldReloader"/>
  <listener event="firstSearcher" class="org.apache.solr.schema.ExternalFileFieldReloader"/>
</schema>
```

I've generated the ./solr/development/data/external_popularity.txt file and I can see those scores with this query on the solr dashboard:

http://localhost:8983/solr/development/select?q={!func}popularity&fl=id,score

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">21</int>
   </lst>
   <result name="response" numFound="7626" start="0" maxScore="21.75">
      <doc>
         <str name="id">Item 9788770781701</str>
         <float name="score">21.75</float>
      </doc>
      <doc>
         <str name="id">Item 9781449661373</str>
         <float name="score">19.0</float>
      </doc>
      <!-- ... -->
   </result>
</response>
```

So now the question is, how do I actually reference this in the Rails project?  I have an Item class with a searchable block:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchable include: [:authors, :publisher, :order_temporary_stock] do
    text :ean
    text :full_title
    text :author_names
    text :publisher_name

    # ...
  end
end
```

...and a typical search:

```
Item.solr_search do
  fulltext self.q do
    phrase_fields full_title:    16.0 # pf: full_title_text^16.0
    phrase_slop 1

    boost_fields ean:            8.0  # qf: ean_text^8.0
    boost_fields author_names:   2.0  # qf: author_names_text^2.0
    boost_fields publisher_name: 2.0  # qf: publisher_name_text^2.0

    # boost(popularity) 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved the above by adding :boost to the search params as follows:

```
Item.solr_search do
  fulltext self.q do
    phrase_fields full_title:    16.0 # pf: full_title_text^16.0
    phrase_slop 1

    boost_fields ean:            8.0  # qf: ean_text^8.0
    boost_fields author_names:   2.0  # qf: author_names_text^2.0
    boost_fields publisher_name: 2.0  # qf: publisher_name_text^2.0
  end

  adjust_solr_params do |params|
    params[:boost] = "popularity_score"
  end
end
```

end